# (python)Getting coordinates of points for dot plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

My data is given as 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, and 0.3.
My goal is to draw dot plot using matplotlib scaterplot by plottting these points which is the solution: (0.1,1) (0.2,1) (0.2,2) (0.2,3) (0.4,1) (0.3,1).
Is there a neat  way to obtain these points above? ※The 0.2 appears three time in my data, therefore  (0.2,1) (0.2,2) and (0.2,3) in the solution.
I've tried Counter class as below, because it counts occurence, it shows only (0.1,1) (0.2,3) (0.4,1) (0.3,1) which is the subset of the solution.

```
x = pd.DataFrame({"X":[0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3]}).X

counter=Counter(x)  # How to get {0.1: 1,0.2: 1, 0.2: 2, 0.2: 3, 0.4: 1, 0.3: 1}  instead of {0.1: 1, 0.2: 3, 0.4: 1, 0.3: 1}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(counter, orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'event', 0:'count'})

plt.scatter(x=df['event'], y=df['count'],alpha=0.3)  # This dot plot is not complete. Because there are no points (0.2,1) and (0.2,2)
```

Comment: Just a hint into another direction: What you are doing here is close to plotting a histogram. The repeated values will stack up on top of each other, giving you the height of the histogram. Your Counter-option does that as well by omitting the single points and just giving you the total height (keep in mind, no information is lost on the way). If you are not set on the scatter plot and if you don't need the single redundant points under the total count specifically, you can use ```plt.hist(x)```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simply the list appending

```
lstevent=[];lstcount=[];
type(lstevent)
for row in df.itertuples():
#     print(row[1],row[2])
#     lstevent.append(row[1]);lstcount.append(row[2]);
    for k in range(row[2]):
        lstevent.append(row[1]);lstcount.append(k+1);
# print(lstevent,lstcount)
df_for_dot=pd.DataFrame({'event': lstevent,'count':lstcount})
df_for_dot
```